# Scrapy - download images from image url list

Tags: scrapy

Scrapy has [ImagesPipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-images-pipeline) that helps download image. the process is

1. Spider: start a link and parse all image urls in response, and save
   image urls to items.
2. ImagesPipeline: items['image_urls'] are processed by ImagesPipeline.

But what if I don't need spider parts and have 100k images URLs ready to be downloaded, for example read URLs from redis, how do I call ImagePipeline directly to download the image?

I know I could simply make Request in spider and save response, but I'd like to see if there is way use default ImagesPipeline to save images directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the use case you describe is the best fit for Scrapy. Wget would work fine for such a constrained problem.

If you really need to use Scrapy for this, make a dummy request to some URL:

```
def start_requests(self):
    request = Request('http://example.com')
    # load from redis
    redis_img_urls = ...
    request.meta['redis_img_urls'] = redis_img_urls
    yield request
```

Then on the `parse()` method return:

```
def parse(self, response):
    return {'image_urls':request.meta['redis_img_urls'] }
```

This is ugly but it should work fine...

P.S. I'm not aware of any easy way to bypass the dummy request and inject and `Item` directly. I'm sure there's one but it's such an unusual thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

The idea behind a scrapy Pipeline is to process the items the spider generates explained [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html).

Now scrapy isn't about "downloading" staff, but a way to create crawlers, spiders, so if you have a list with urls to "download", then just use for loop and download them.

If you still want to use a scrapy Pipeline, then you'll have to return an item with that list inside the `image_urls` field.

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield Request('http://httpbin.org/ip', callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    ...
    yield {'image_urls': [your list]}
```

Then enable the pipeline on settings.